# WaterTank ProducerConsumer Pattern

Tags: java, concurrent-programming

this is an exercise where i have 1 Producer and N Consumer ( fill and remove Water into an WaterTank ) which i implemented in the shown code.

Now the text of the exercise says:
Filling an additional tank:
*This way u can be sure that water won't be put in and taken away at the same time.
Or you could as well say that water can only be taken away if there is a putOperation.*

I don't understand it. I have synchronized on an private final object so the first part ( won't be put and taken away at the same time ) doesn't  happen anyway. Also there is no need for an additional Watertank that way.

The second part where it will be taken at the same time it will be put i also quite don't understand. Do i need Semaphores or Reeantrantlock or anything?

I know i have to put an WaterTank Object into my already existing WaterTank as far as i understand.

Thy for any help :)

```
public class WaterTank {

  private final int capacity;
  private int water;
  private final Object synchobj = new Object();

  public WaterTank(int capacit, int wate) {
    this.capacity = capacit;
    this.water = wate;
  }

  public void fillwater(int wata) {

    synchronized (synchobj) {
      if (water + wata > capacity) {
        System.out.println("Cannot fill water!");

      } else {
        water = water + wata;
        System.out.println("FILL::::Capacity: " + capacity + " and Water: " + water);
      }
    }
  }

  public void removewater(int wata) {
    synchronized (synchobj) {
      if (water - wata < 0) {
        System.out.println("Cannot take water!");
      } else {
        water = water - wata;
        System.out.println("REMOVE:::Capacity: " + capacity + " and Water: " + water);
      }
    }
  }
}

public class Producer implements Runnable {
  private final WaterTank T;

  public Producer(WaterTank t) {
    this.T = t;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      T.fillwater(10);
    }
  }
}

public class Consumer implements Runnable {

  private final WaterTank T;

  public Consumer(WaterTank t) {
    this.T = t;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      T.removewater(10);
    }
  }
}

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    WaterTank F = new WaterTank(100, 0);

    Thread Pro = new Thread(new Producer(F));
    Pro.start();
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      exec.execute(new Consumer(F));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thinking about it i might need wait/notify for the second part of the question.

Comment: Are you required to do this at this low a level? Because normally, I'd implement producer-consumer using a [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

Comment: is there a requirement for producer to block if tank is full or for consumer to block when it is empty?

Comment: @millimoose: yes we are allowed to do it but this exercise is especially to do it without a blocking queue 

at second poster here is no explicit saying about that but i have tried it both ways but my wait notify doesn't work, i post it here

Comment: Your original code is correct in that it doesn't allow adding and removing at the same time. It also doesn't allow to take away water that is not there or to add when tank is full. Adding wait/notify allows you to implement blocking when tank is full / empty but this seems not to be purpose of the exercise. I think you first priority is not to code but understand the requirements.